# Pd-catalysed hydrogenation of imines

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis, adsorption

Hydrogenation of imines to amines by $\ce{H2}$ on $\ce{Pd/C}$ has been used e.g. in the synthesis of Pumiliotoxin. By contrast, carbonyl groups are rarely reduced in this way, which I though was due to the fact that if a carbonyl is adsorbed, the interaction is through O’s lone pairs, rather than C=O $\pi$. However, the lone pair on the imine N should be of an even higher energy than in carbonyl and so should adsorb more easily. Why then does the hydrogenation of imines happen successfully?

Comment: I feel like the polarity of the bond might play a role, but not sure

Comment: The HOMO should be the $\ce{C=X}$ bond either way …

Comment: @Jan So why does the adsorption of carbonyls occur at O? And does it actually?

Comment: @substitutedbutadiene I wouldn’t be sure, I would have to look through the literature. Heterogenous catalysis is really not my strong point … ^^'

Comment: Depending what you look for and where you get the information,  I was under the impression the typical C=O is around 100kJ/mol stronger than the typical C=N bond.  Hence, the latter is easier to break.  Stronger adsorption is backed up by the fact that the resultant amines,  in certain circumstances,  can poison catalysts, whereas alcohols do not tend to.